# Given a list 1, 4, 5,9,2 write a program to find possible combinations of two values where sum = 6

Tags: java, arrays

Given array a= [1,4,5,9,2].I need to find/print combinations of two values where sum = 6.

My code is as below : (it's O(n^2) and not efficient). Any better solutions -

```
for(int out=0;out<a.length-1;out++)
{
    for(int in=out+1;in<N;in++)
    {
    if(a[out]+a[in]==6)
    { 
    System.out.println("The 2 numbers are: "+ a[out] +", "+ a[in]);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: For small N, 1) it doesn't matter if the solution is efficient, and 2) `O(N^2)` may be faster than `O(N)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Place all numbers into a `HashSet`.
2. Iterate over the array, and for each item `val`, check whether `6-val` is in the `HashSet`.

I'm not showing code since this looks like homework (if it is, please tag it as such).

Also, for short arrays your `O(n^2)` solution is almost certainly going to be faster than this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aix. This is not a homework problem. While looking for SD interview questions I stumbled on the above question. Now i have added the 'interview' tag.

Comment: I can confirm this is a pretty standard interview question. When I was interviewing this came up in like every 1 of 5 interviews. Also your answer is best... it only traverses the list twice, which is an O(n) solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int out=0;out<a.length-1;out++)
{
    int value = a[out];
    int required = 6 - value;
    //now check if the required number is in the array

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the solution given by srock should be like below

```
int length = a.length;

for(int out = 0; out < length ; out++) {
   for(int inn = 0; inn < length; inn ++) {
      if ((inn != out) && ((a[inn] + a[out]) == 6))
      sysout("The valid combination is "+a[inn]+" "+a[out])
   }
 }
```

And ofcourse this need to iterate length*length times. As mentioned by aix If we use Hashset with contains will iterate only length no of times and contains method will directly go to the bucket location using the hashcode and will fetch the data to compare. So this HashSet::contains way is best for large no datas.